# gcc compile error ld cannot find -l Permission denied

Tags: gcc

When I execute:

```
gcc D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

it reports the error:

```
D:\project\c\test\collection>gcc D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
    d:/gcc-9.2.0-no-debug/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
    cannot find D:\project\c\test\collection: Permission denied
    d:/gcc-9.2.0-no-debug/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
    cannot find -lfoo
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I followed the steps found here: [gcc example](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)

My OS is Windows 10 and I use `cmd` with administrator role.

---

**UPDATE 1**

I execute:

```
gcc -L D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

and get the error:

```
gcc -L D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
d:/gcc-9.2.0-no-debug/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfoo
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My collection directory has `libfoo.so` file:

```
2019/12/28  11:19    <DIR>          .
2019/12/28  11:19    <DIR>          ..
2019/12/28  10:55             3,262 a.exe
2019/12/28  10:38                87 foo.c
2019/12/28  10:37                80 foo.h
2019/12/28  10:38               838 foo.o
2019/12/28  10:38            47,372 libfoo.so
2019/12/28  10:38               134 main.c
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I change to execute:

```
 gcc -L / -Wall -o test main.c
```

and get the error:

```
//libfoo.dll.a: Unrecognized file: File truncated,collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I've restructured the question so that it flows better with updates, and fixed various spelling, grammar and formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Files that aren't part of an option (like `-o test` or `-lfoo`) are generally considered to be input files for compiling or linking.

There's a good chance that's meant to be a library location for locating the  `foo` library, simply because the tutorial you're following has almost the exact same line:

```
gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

If that's the case, then you're *missing* the `-L` to tell it this should be added to the library search path, so something like this should fix it:

```
gcc -L D:\project\c\test\collection  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

---

In any case, since you appear to have all your files in a single directory (source, libs, etc), you don't *need* to adjust the search path. Or, if you do, you can just used `-L.` to specify the current directory, something like:

```
gcc -Wall -o test main.c -L. -lfoo
```

Comment: very thanks your answer,i execute your command,and get another error,i update my question.

Comment: @Amitābha, have you tried it with just the `-L.`? I'm not sure how smart MinGW is so it *could* be treating the `\t` in `...\test\...` as a tab. If so, you may be able to use `/` as a separator instead or, as suggested, just `.` since everything seems to be in the same directory.

Comment: i use gcc -L /  -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo,report //libfoo.dll.a:  Unrecognized file: File truncated,collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Amitābha: Just to be clearer, I'm not sure if you understood what I was saying but the command you used in the previous comment makes me think not :-) Try `gcc -Wall -o test main.c -L. -lfoo` from within the directory where everything is. If that doesn't work then it's possibly a foible of MinGW and you may want to consider a different toolchain.